# maximum subsequence in c++

Tags: c++, sequence, subsequence

**Question:**

Where is the error in my code?

**Promlem:**

I would like to find the maximum unique subsequence in a string. Example: For `aabbaba` the answer would be 2 (`ab` or `ba`). I would like to do that by iterating the string only once. Only lower-case letters are allowed.

As @hvd pointed out, a subsequence is unique, if all letters in it are unique. There can be the same unique subsequence in the string several times.

**Approach:**

- start at first letter of string and iterate to end
- write the position the letter occured in vector `unique`, if you did not already see the letter
- increase the count for this subsequence
- if you saw the letter, start a new subsequence. Init the new subsequence with the distance from your current position to the last occurrence. Example: String is `exampletzu`. We are at the second e. Current index is 6. Current max subsequence is 6 (`exampl`). Go to t and create a new subsequence. Init it to 7 (`xamplet`).
- You know that you can abort, if the current subsequence is equal to 26, because that is the maximum possible

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef vector<int>::iterator it;

    int length = 7;
    string p = "aabbaba";
    // result
    vector<int> max(length, 0);
    int subSeq = 0;

    // alphabet
    vector<int> unique(26, -1);
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        int pos = (p[i] - 97) % 26;
        if (unique[pos] != -1)
        {
            // letter already existed. Start new max
            ++subSeq;
            max[subSeq] = i - unique[pos] - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < unique.size(); ++j)
            {
                if (unique[j] != -1)
                {
                    unique[j] = unique[pos];
                }
            }
        }
        ++max[subSeq];
        if (max[subSeq] == 26)
        {
            flag == true;
            break;
        }
        unique[pos] = i;
    }

    int result = 0;
    if (!flag)
    {
        for (it i = max.begin(); i != max.end(); ++i)
        {
            if (*i > result)
            {
                result = *i;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 26;
    }
    cout << result << endl;
    cout.flush();
     }
```

Comment: I can't make sense of your example. Why is `ab` a unique subsequence if it appears in your example input twice? What does "maximum" mean here? This suggests to me you want the longest, but the longest is trivially the input string itself, so that isn't what you want either.

Comment: How the code is tested? You might  change `string p = argc > 1 ? argv[1] 
 : "aabbaba";`  to be able to test your problem with very simple input - then the error should be obvious

Comment: @hvd Maybe the word unique was misleading. In the subsequence `ab` all letters are unique.

Comment: @User12547645 Ah! Thanks, that makes more sense.

Comment: @hvd I will add that in the description

Comment: @PiotrNycz Here are some examples of output the function gives `is` and the output it should give `should `
**Format:** is - should - string,

4 - 2 - aabbaba, 

4 - 4 - repeat,

1 - 1 - aaa,

6 - 6 - professor,

Comment: I think I see the error: when you update `unique`, you should leave those letters alone which have already occurred since unique[pos]: if (unique[j] < unique[pos]) {unique[j] = unique[pos];}

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Good suggestion, but that would mean, that we would bias the new sequence. **Example:** `zaxbcdxefgz`. If we do not update, we would get the longest distance from `z` to `z`, even though there is an interrupt (`x`) in between.

Comment: I don't think so; my suggestion is a restriction. Did you try it?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Yes. 
Results in Format is - should - string: 3 - 2 - aabbaba, 4 - 4 - repeat, 1 - 1 - aaa, 7 - 6 - professor

Comment: If you take `professor` as an example, you can see that the correct max seq. would be `profes`, with length 6. With the change, the algorithm chooses `ofessor`, with length 7.

Comment: I get 6. Maybe you misunderstood my change.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Could you pls. submit your change as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you update `unique`, you should leave those letters alone which have already occurred since `unique[pos]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef vector<int>::iterator it;

    p = argv[1];
    length = p.length();
    // result
    vector<int> max(length, 0);
    int subSeq = 0;

    // alphabet
    vector<int> unique(26, -1);
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        int pos = (p[i] - 97) % 26;
        if (unique[pos] != -1)
        {
            // letter already existed. Start new max
            ++subSeq;
            max[subSeq] = i - unique[pos] - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < unique.size(); ++j)
            {
                if (unique[j] != -1)
                {
          if (unique[j] < unique[pos]) {
                    unique[j] = unique[pos];
          }
                }
            }
        }
        ++max[subSeq];
        if (max[subSeq] == 26)
        {
            flag == true;
            break;
        }
        unique[pos] = i;
    }

    int result = 0;
    if (!flag)
    {
        for (it i = max.begin(); i != max.end(); ++i)
        {
            if (*i > result)
            {
                result = *i;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = 26;
    }
    cout << result << endl;
    cout.flush();
     }
```